# Base address of UART4 for omap-4460

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

From the kernel 3.4 [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.4),I could not make out that where the UART Base address is mapped ?As far as I know for mapping the base address we should use `request_mem_region` and `io_remap` function.But I could not find this in the code.Base address for UART4 is 0x4806E000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be defined in the dts file in arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4.dtsi file. I'm not sure if DT is enabled for your kernel.If enabled, it reads in the probe function

Comment: @Asha.What is DT? How is it enabled

Comment: DT is Device tree. A quick check to find your board supports device tree, you can check your board file 
DT_MACHINE_START(BOARD-NAME, "board-name"), then your board supports Device Tree. Also, you can check your .config file for CONFIG_USE_OF. This confirms if Flattened Device Tree is supported for your board.

Comment: @Asha.Where to get the board name from?How is the arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4.dtsi file linked to omap-serial.c in the kernel source tree?